# Moving point plot for 2 variable function Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

For the function `z= 10+pow((x-2),2)+pow((y+5),2)`, I want to represent in a 3D plot every value of `z`  for each `(x,y)` pair , with a display delay before each new value of `z` (like a moving point).

The values for `x,y` are read from files.

I tried to modify Jacobs code from [Creating a point moving along a graph in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959528/creating-a-point-moving-along-a-graph-in-matlab/4959858#4959858), but I couldn't get it to work for my 2 variable function.

I would like a general solution, because I will also need this plotting for a N-variable function.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following question and see if it answers yours:

[animate plot / trajectory in matlab / octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574126/animate-3d-plot-in-matlab-octave/16581992)