# How to Draw animated Figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, animation, figure

I want to draw a moving point on matlab figure, but i need the figure to move while drawing the new position of the point. To be more clear, i want to achieve this effect(
[Moving Vehicle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxNxADPnlTk)).

I found related questions [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959528/creating-a-point-moving-along-a-graph-in-matlab) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688688/how-to-do-an-animated-plot-in-matlab) but they don't solve my issue.

Comment: there are many different ways to reproduce the animation in your link, but your request is not defined enough. Nobody is going to write something like that from scratch to be told later that you wanted something different. Try something based on the answer you linked, then post your code and explain what works and what still doesn't work for you. _Hint: to get the figure moving around, when you refresh you just have to set the limits of the axes centred on the last point you drew._

Comment: Nice hint. I will do it and get back with my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from @`Hoki`, i solved this issue.

`ff` is the array of `n` data points (x,y) with size (n*2). Because my points are within a narrow range with step 0.001, i used `dx` and `dy` with these particular values. It depends on the point steps.

```
clf(figure(3)), hold on
dx = 0.001;
dy = 0.001;
for i = 1 : length(ff)-1
    minx = ff(i,1)-dx;
    miny = ff(i,2)-dy;
    maxx = ff(i,1)+dx;
    maxy = ff(i,2)+dy;
    plot(ff(i,1),ff(i,2),'o');
    axis([minx maxx miny maxy]);
    hold on
    pause(0.001)
end
hold off
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fifo buffer to release old points and to add new points. The function 'drawnow' is faster than 'pause':

```
close all
clear

NUM_OF_POINTS=100; % number of points displayed on plot
f=@(x) sin(2*pi*x); % function to plot
x_t=zeros(1,NUM_OF_POINTS); %x buffer
y_t=zeros(1,NUM_OF_POINTS); %y buffer

figure
keypressed=[];
set(gcf,'keypress','keypressed=get(gcf,''currentchar'');');
counter=0;
for t = 0:0.01:100
     counter=counter+1;
     %% Handle keyboard keys
     if ~isempty(keypressed)
          if(abs(keypressed)==27), break; end; %escape key. end
          if strcmp(keypressed,' '), keyboard; end; %spacebar key. pause
          keypressed=[];
     end

     %% Fill the buffer
     x_t=[x_t(2:end), t]; %fifo buffer
     y_t=[y_t(2:end), f(t)]; %fifo buffer

     %% Plot the buffer
     plot(x_t,y_t)
     drawnow; % this is the fastest for 'draw and continue'
     pause(0.01); %you can add delay to slow the move effect
end
```